# Printing Specific Data From Table Using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first time posting a question on this site; be gentle, please. This isn't homework. I'll try to be as concise as possible.

I have a table with 5 keyword columns, a date column, and a user ID column for identifying what user added that specific row of data. My goal is to print and count the number of matched keywords from a row iff:

1) Another row(s) contains those keywords AND has the same date.

2) The user ID for each row is unique.

For example:

Row1=> keyword1:(K1) keyword2:(K2) keyword3:(K3) keyword4:(K4) keyword5:(K5) date:(D1) user_id:(U1)

Row2=> keyword1:(K6) keyword2:(K7) keyword3:(K1) keyword4:(K2) keyword5:(K8) date:(D1) user_id:(U2)

Row3=> keyword1:(K6) keyword2:(K7) keyword3:(K1) keyword4:(K2) keyword5:(K8) date:(D2) user_id:(U2)

Row4=> keyword1:(K1) keyword2:(K2) keyword3:(K3) keyword4:(K4) keyword5:(K5) date:(D2) user_id:(U3)

Output: 
K1 (2 times), K2 (2 times), on D1
K1 (2 times), K2 (2 times), on D2

Row3 should be excluded from the first count because even though the words matched, the user was a duplicate.

Here's how I've started:

```
<% @prophecies.each do |prophecy| %>
  <% date1 = prophecy.datetwo %>
  <% @prophecies.each do |prophecy| %>
    <% if date1.eql?(prophecy.datetwo) == true %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= prophecy.keyone %></td>
        <td><%= prophecy.keytwo %></td>
        <td><%= prophecy.keythree %></td>
        <td><%= prophecy.keyfour %></td>
        <td><%= prophecy.keyfive %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it's nowhere near what I'd like to accomplish. If anyone could even help me sort out the pseudocode for this I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to do it in your model, not in your view. 
You can define methods in your prophecy class something like that

```
def self.keywords_at_day(date)
  #find prophecies for particular dae
  prophecies = self.find_by(date:date)

  # create hash with keywords for user
  user_keywords = {}
  prophecies.each do |prophecy|
    user_keywords[prophecy.user] ||= []
    user_keywords[prophecy.user] << prophecy.keyword
  end

  # create general array with all keywords
  keywords = []
  user_keywords.each do |user, kw|
    keywords << kw.uniq
  end

  # count keywords
  keywords_count = {}
  keywords.each do |keyword|
    keywords_count[keyword] ||= 0
    keywords_count[keyword] += 1
  end
  keywords_count
end

def self.keywoards_lists
  dates = Prophecy.all.map{|p| p.date}.uniq
  keywords_lists = {}
  dates.each do |date|
    keywords_lists[date] = keywords_at_day(date)
  end
  keywords_lists
end
```

You controller

```
def index
  @keywords_lists = Prophecy.keywords_lists
end
```

View

```
<%= @keywords_lists.each do |date, keywords_list| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= date %> </td>
    <td> 
      <%= keywords_list.each do |keyword, count| %> 
        <%= "#{keyword} encountered #{count} times" %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If it's really not homework, I suggest you to read about MVC, ruby name convention(date_two instead of datetwo), booleans (you don't need "==true" for eql?).
And besides all it's not good type of question for stackoverflow

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a data structure that match your need. BAsically a hash where key is keyword, and content the list of uid that uniquely use your keyword:

```
r=[]<<{:keyword1=>"K1",keyword2:"K2",keyword3:"K3",keyword4:"k4",:date=>d1,uid:1}
r<<{:keyword1=>"K6",keyword2:"K7",keyword3:"K1",keyword4:"k2",:date=>d1,uid:2}
r<<{:keyword1=>"K6",keyword2:"K7",keyword3:"K1",keyword4:"k2",:date=>d2,uid:2}
```

(just for test purposes)
then:

```
r.inject({}) do |sum,aRow|              
 # loop for all keywords in the row.
 [:keyword1,:keyword2,:keyword3,:keyword4,:keyword4].each do |keyword|
    # get each entry or create it
    sum[aRow[keyword]]=elem=sum[aRow[keyword]]||{}

    count=elem[aRow[:date]]||{:users=>Set.new}
    count[:users]<<aRow[:uid]
    elem[aRow[:date]]=count 
  end
  sum
end
```

The result if the following:

```
=> {"K1"=>
  {2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {1, 2}>},
   2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0100=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>}},
 "K2"=>{2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {1}>}},
 "K3"=>{2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {1}>}},
 "k4"=>{2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {1}>}},
 "K6"=>
  {2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0100=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>},
   2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>}},
 "K7"=>
  {2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0100=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>},
   2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>}},
 "k2"=>
  {2014-01-01 00:00:00 +0100=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>},
   2014-09-04 15:05:21 +0200=>{:users=>#<Set: {2}>}}
```

So you know that keyword "K1" has been used with two different date, and by two users (1,2) for first one, and 2 for second date.

Than, it will be easy to display this array.